# CollectionView Horizontal scroll not working in ios 7

Tags: ios

CollectionView horizontal scroll not working in ios 7 but it's working fine in ios 8 and 9. Is there any solution for this ?

The Code is here:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(330, 100);

collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 350, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
collection.delegate = self;
collection.dataSource = self;
collection.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
collection.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

[collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

```
[self.view addSubview:collection];
```

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Comment: if i am using view controller its working fine. when i am displaying it on view scroll not working

Comment: you are adding collectionview inside scollview ??

Comment: @Sudha, Please review edited answer & let us know ur comments!

Comment: No i'm not using scroll view. Adding Collection view on UIView

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've used a line of code after adding collectionView on view that its working fine in ios 7 also.

add this code after [self addSubview:self.collectionView];

here the code:

[self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

- (void)update {
  [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1, 0)];
  }

Comment: But if I'm using [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1, 0)]; directly in collection view then it's crashing.

Answer (score 0):

It now fits my needs, and could be useful for someone else, so here is my code: 
I have tested In iOS7-8-9. Below example is for Default iPad. You Just need to change target settings and O.S Version.

**https://github.com/philippeauriach/fullyhorizontalcollectionview**

Please download it & let us know ur comments. Happy Coding!

If you want to add collection view onto the View then use below code. Below code into i have created CL View programmatically and It's also working correctly with Autolayout and iOS 7-8-9. Please implement below code and let us know ur comments.

**.H File**

```
@interface HorizontalCollectionViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>{

    NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedCell;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *horizonCLView;
```

**.M File**

```
#import "HorizontalCollectionViewController.h"
static NSString * const CellIdentifier = @“horizonCell";

@interface HorizontalCollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation HorizontalCollectionViewController

@synthesize horizonCLView;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"view frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));


    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self viewDidLayoutSubviews];


    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = self.view.frame.size;
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [layout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.f];
    [layout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.f];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);


    horizonCLView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    horizonCLView.dataSource = self;
    horizonCLView.delegate = self;
    horizonCLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    horizonCLView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [horizonCLView setBounces:NO];
    [horizonCLView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [horizonCLView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [horizonCLView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self.view addSubview:horizonCLView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    //Select Current Image For Sare In Social Media
   // currentImageIndex = selectedCell;

    [horizonCLView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:selectedCell inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];

    CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.horizonCLView.contentOffset, .size = self.horizonCLView.bounds.size};
    CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
    visibleIndexPath = [self.horizonCLView indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];

  //  NSLog(@"visibleIndexPath.row in View will appear %ld",(long)visibleIndexPath.row);

    //SelectedCell is a selected image from gallary view
    NSLog(@"selectedCell in View will appear: %ld",(long)selectedCell);


}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [dataAry count];
}

#pragma Here we set the frame of horizontal scrll view
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // expand cell to fill the entire view
    return collectionView.frame.size;

}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.title = [[self.dataAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@“dataAryName"];

    //imageVI.image = nil;

    imageVI = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    if (!imageVI){

        imageVI = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        imageVI.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageVI.tag = 100;
        imageVI.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageVI];

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [asSetLib assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.dataAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"dataAryName"]] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

            // imageVI.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage];
            imageVI.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.defaultRepresentation.fullResolutionImage];
            NSLog(@"Preview view into album loaded successfully!");

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred while loading image: %@", error.description);
        }];

    });


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Please share for iphone because the problem is with ios 7 only above that my code is working fine

Comment: @Sudha, It is Universal. If u have download then change project setting. Make it iPhone. Below code is also universal and also perfectly work with iOS7.

Comment: Well, I found the solution for my problem. I've added one line of code: [self performSelector:@selector(update) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

Comment: - (void)update {
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1, 0)];
} After using this code is working in ios 7 also.

Comment: But if I'm using  [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1, 0)]; directly its getting crash. Any Idea about it ?

Comment: @Sudha, Please review my another answer and let us know ur comments.

Comment: I am adding some code here ...   self.collectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1;
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:self.collectionViewFlowLayout];[self addSubview:self.collectionView];

Comment: for defining layout i used - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize size = collectionView.frame.size;
    
    if (self.type == NativeViewTypeGrid) {
        CGFloat height = collectionView.frame.size.height;
        size = CGSizeMake(height * 0.9, height);
    }
    
    return size;
}

Answer (score 0):

Sudha, I think this issues in your code not an iOS7 issues.
Here, I have review two bug in ur code.

1)In this line you have give static width of collection view,

```
collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 350, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Instead Of it will be goes look like,

```
collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Make sure your collection view width size always go with according to your view size.

2)Make sure, Your layout item size width higher then collection view width frame. Otherwise Scrolling was not effected.

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width+10, 100);
```

3) Carefully use,

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

delegate method of collectionview layout size method.

4)Finally your code look like,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width+10, 100);
    [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

    collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    collection.delegate = self;
    collection.dataSource = self;
    collection.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    collection.pagingEnabled = YES;
    collection.scrollEnabled = YES;
    collection.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [self.view addSubview:collection];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return  cell;

}


Happy Coding!
```

Comment: I am doing in the same way as you've done. It's working in ios 8 and 9 but not in 7.  I got the solution, I posted the answer too.

Comment: @Sudha, can you share your demo project with me? I think your solution is not proper way.

Comment: layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width+10, 100); also does not make collection cell scrolling

Comment: I am implementing the collection view in a sdk. And got the solution for my problem which I already posted.